python mock AttributeError: object has no attribute
I am trying to write a unit test to assert that a class method from another class is called in a particular class method.
I have tried mocking however I am getting error message: AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'b. at the b.bar() line See simplified reproduction of error:

class A:
   def __init__(self, has_b=True):
      if has_b:
         self.b = b()
   def foo(self):
      return self.b.bar()


class B:
   def __init__(self):
      pass
   def bar(self):
      return True


#Outside the B class:
def b() -> B:
   return B()

  
#Unit Test 
class TestA(TestCase):
   def setUp(self):
      self.mock_b_methods = mock.MagicMock()
      self.A = A()
   def test_foo(self):
      self.mock_b_methods.bar.return_value = True
      res = self.A.foo()
      assertTrue(res)


Please make this script really reproducible for us. I strongly suspect that you edited it between trying and posting, and when adding the import statements and prepending self. to the last line, it works for me. Also, your code does not a) set the mock method to A, nor checks whether a class method is called. Please try to clarify this first.


I am trying to write a unit test to assert that a class method from another class is called in a particular class method.

My answer is regarding this statement of yours, while your code does a lot of other things, see my comment under the question.
If you want to test that B.bar is called from A.foo, then I propose this code:
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = B()

    def foo(self):
        return self.b.bar()

class B:
    def bar(self):
        # want to test whether this code is called!?
        return True

# Unit Test
class TestA(TestCase):
    @patch.object(B, 'bar')
    def test(self, mock_method):
        a = A()
        a.foo()
        mock_method.assert_called()

I stripped it from the if test on has_b that you didn't use anyhow, and the function b(), but you can re-introduce that without issues.
The key is to use mock.patch, easiest as a decorator to the test method, to replace it with a mock_method, which will then be provided as an argument to the test function. Then you can do your calls and finally assess that it has been called.
See here for more documentation on the patch function.
